# Launching GHCi with a Turtle Script

Tags: haskell, haskell-turtle

Suppose one has a turtle script, but doesn't want to run it. Is there a way to launch a stack ghci environment with all of the functions loaded from the script?

Comment: What about that script makes just `:load`ing into a normal GHCi session impossible?

Comment: @leftaroundabout: Nothing -- this is the solution.